# C# How do I correctly deserialize multiple custom objects in an array to an object?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am retrieving a json object with an array, which contains multiple object types.

Given I retrieve a JSON payload that looks like this:

```
{
   "Lines": [
   {
       "PropertyA": "A",
       "PropertyB": "B"
   },
   {
       "Property01": 1,
       "Property02": 2
   }]
}
```

I want to deserialize this into a single object list.

Example:

```
public List<Line> Lines;
```

So I can compare the object with one I expect.

What I have so far:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string PropertyA = "A";
    public string PropertyB = "B";
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Property01 = 01;
    public int Property02 = 02;
}

public class MainClass
{
    public List<dynamic> Lines;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\r\n \"Lines\": [\r\n {\r\n \"PropertyA\": \"A\",\r\n \"PropertyB\": \"B\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Property01\": 1,\r\n \"Property02\": 2\r\n }]\r\n}";

        MainClass actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(json);

        MainClass expected = new MainClass()
        {
            Lines = new List<dynamic>()
            {
                new Class1(),
                new Class2()
            }
        };

        actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Your inner sections (propa, propb and prop1, prop2) are going to deserialize as JSON arrays and not something you can deserialize into classes like you want.  You will have to navigate through the array and get the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can verify the propriety name and deserialize  in right object like that

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var class1List = new List<Class1>();
        var class2List = new List<Class2>();
        var genericList = new List<dynamic>();

        var actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        foreach (var item in actual.Lines)
        {

            string itemJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
            if (itemJson.Contains("PropertyA"))
            {
                var class1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(itemJson);
                class1List.Add(class1);
                genericList.Add(class1);
            }
            else
            {
                var class2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class2>(itemJson);
                class2List.Add(class2);
                genericList.Add(class2);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string PropertyA;
    public string PropertyB;
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Property01;
    public int Property02;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Parsing it myself like you've shown here probably is the best way for me to do it while keeping my classes separate.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly change fields to properties. Then the easiest way here is to create one common object representing both objects like this:

```
public class Class1
{   
    public string PropertyA {get;set;}
    public string PropertyB {get;set;}
    public int Property01 {get;set;}
    public int Property02 {get;set;}
}

public class MainClass
{
    public List<Class1> Lines;
}
```

and deserialization would look like this:

```
 MainClass actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(json);
```

If you change class definition of Class1 to object with nullable properties you'll be able to detect if property existed in the json to differentiate between both objects:

```
public class Class1
{   
    public string PropertyA {get;set;}
    public string PropertyB {get;set;}
    public int? Property01 {get;set;}
    public int? Property02 {get;set;}
}
```

Another way is to use JArray and continue with your logic using this object:

```
JArray arr = JArray.Parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an abstract class, **Line**, from which **Class1** and **Class2** will inherit:

```
public abstract class Line
{
}

public class Class1 : Line
{
    public string PropertyA = "A";
    public string PropertyB = "B";
}

public class Class2 : Line
{
    public int Property01 = 01;
    public int Property02 = 02;
}
```

Your **MainClass** will use a List of **Line** instead of dynamic:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

Then, to handle the instanciation of **Class1** and **Class2** from the Json Serializer, you can define a **JsonConverter**:

```
public class LineConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Line));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var line = default(Line);

        if (jsonObject["PropertyA"] != null)
        {
            line = new Class1();
        }
        else if (jsonObject["Property01"] != null)
        {
            line = new Class2();
        }

        serializer.Populate(jsonObject.CreateReader(), line);
        return line;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // Implement if you're serializing the objects back to JSON
    }
}
```

And use this converter in the JsonSerializer settings:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{\r\n \"Lines\": [\r\n {\r\n \"PropertyA\": \"A\",\r\n \"PropertyB\": \"B\"\r\n },\r\n {\r\n \"Property01\": 1,\r\n \"Property02\": 2\r\n }]\r\n}";

        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new LineConverter());
        MainClass actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(json, serializerSettings);

        MainClass expected = new MainClass()
        {
            Lines = new List<Line>()
            {
                new Class1(),
                new Class2()
            }
        };

        actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use case, but an alternative workaround might be to *not* use an array of mixed types, and break up each into their own property i.e.

```json
{
   "Lines": {
        "AlphaLines": [
            {
                "PropertyA": "A",
                "PropertyB": "B",
                "Index": 0
            }
        ],
        "NumericLines": [
            {
                "Property01": 1,
                "Property02": 2,
                "Index": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It really depends if you own the structure of the incoming JSON and you have the ability to reformat as needed.  But the flip side is, it makes the *serialization part super simple*.

And if you share an interface with each that contains an `Index` property

```cs
public interface ILine
{
    int Index {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can stitch them back together in the original order

```cs
var allLines = p.Lines.AlphaLines.Cast<ILine>().Concat(p.Lines.NumericLines).OrderBy(x => x.Index);
```

#### [Demo in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w7XWKD)

Again, might not be the best for everyone, but really depends on the structure of your data, and how many different classes you might be mixing.

Answer (score -2):

To correctly deserialize multiple custom objects in an array to one object in C#, you can use the Newtonsoft.Json (also known as Json.NET) library. Here's an example of how to do it:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Line
{
public string PropertyA { get; set; }
public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
public List<dynamic> Lines { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string json = "{\"Lines\": [{\"PropertyA\": \"A\", \"PropertyB\": \"B\"}, {\"Property01\": 1,}"
```

Comment: All posts on Stack Overflow have to be written in English.